# R - How to choose rows based on values in column

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe, data, shown below:

```
head(data)
      code       x     y        z        new
1   123456       1     2        0     654321 
2   999999       2     3        0     543210
3   000998       3     4        0     887765
4   106813       4     6        0         NA
5   222345       5     6        0     564738
6   106815       6     5        0         NA
7   887765       7     1        1     000998
```

I am trying to make sure that the linked data is kept. For example, if i make a new matrix by subsetting the data so that it only keeps rows with `x < 4`:

```
data2 <- subset(data,x<4)
data2
    Code x y z    new
1 123456 1 2 0 654321
2 999999 2 3 0 543210
3 000998 3 4 0 887765
```

I would then like to add any rows in which the `new` value for a row in the subsetted data (data2) is equal to the `code` value of a row that was in the original data, like so:

```
data3
    Code x y z    new
1 123456 1 2 0 654321
2 999999 2 3 0 543210
3 000998 3 4 0 887765
4 887765 7 1 1 000998
```

Comment: @TheTime careful in case you duplicate rows that are in data2 where condition `data$code %in% data2$new` is also true

Answer (score 2):

This is not the prettiest but it works

```
rbind(data2, merge(data, data2[,"new", drop = FALSE], by.x = "code", by.y = "new"))
```